# Is there a method just write `____` to get a underline hphantom, which width is 4em?

Tags: symbols

I need typography some fillblank items. I want write

```
\item We are ____ sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
```

instead of

```
\newcommand{\blanks}[1][4em]{\underline{\makebox[#1]{}}}
...
\item We are \blanks sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
```

for readability. Could anybody help me?

EDIT

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,url,graphicx}% or hyperref

% \newcommand*{\blanks}[1][4em]{\rule{#1}{.4pt}}

% \catcode`\_=\active

% \def_{\blanks[1em]}

% \everymath{\catcode`\_=8\relax}

% \newcommand*{\makeunderscorenormal}{\catcode`\_=8\relax}
% \newcommand*{\makeunderscoreweird}{\catcode`\_=\active}
% \newcommand*{\blank}[1]{\blanks[\widthof{#1}]}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{a_b/1.png}
% We are ____ sure that his skills qualify him for the job.

    % We are \blank{not} sure that his skills qualify him for the job.

    % \url{http://www.tex_stackexchange.com}

    $ 1_2 $
\end{document}
```

does work, while

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,url,graphicx}% or hyperref

\newcommand*{\blanks}[1][4em]{\rule{#1}{.4pt}}

\catcode`\_=\active

\def_{\blanks[1em]}

\everymath{\catcode`\_=8\relax}

\newcommand*{\makeunderscorenormal}{\catcode`\_=8\relax}
\newcommand*{\makeunderscoreweird}{\catcode`\_=\active}
\newcommand*{\blank}[1]{\blanks[\widthof{#1}]}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{a_b/1.png}
We are ____ sure that his skills qualify him for the job.

    We are \blank{not} sure that his skills qualify him for the job.

    \url{http://www.tex_stackexchange.com}

    $ 1_2 $
\end{document}
```

does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make `_` active (and change its definition in math-mode “back” to a sub-script).

I also added an option with the `\blank` macro that makes a rule just as long as the given text.

I also added the macros `\makeunderscorenormal` and `\makeunderscoreweird` to change back to its normal definition (i.e. a math-subscript, i.e. errors in text-mode).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,url}% or hyperref

\newcommand*{\blanks}[1][4em]{\rule{#1}{.4pt}}
\newcommand*{\blank}[1]{\blanks[\widthof{#1}]}

\begingroup
    \catcode`\_=\active
    \gdef_{\blanks[1em]}
\endgroup
\everymath{\catcode`\_=8\relax}

\newcommand*{\makeunderscorenormal}{\catcode`\_=8\relax}
\newcommand*{\makeunderscoreweird}{\catcode`\_=\active}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}\makeunderscoreweird
        \item We are ____ sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
        \item We are \blank{not} sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
    \end{itemize}
    \url{http://www.tex_stackexchange.com}

    $ 1_2 $
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, your definition changed the behavior of `_`, so if there is an URL in document, it will be wrong. I need only four continuous `_`.

Comment: @cowkileg Well, don't you want `_`’s definition to change? By the way, I don't get a problem with an `_` in an URL, see my updated answer. Can you make an example where it went wrong?

Comment: @cowkileg In that case and as I couldn’t find the appropriate places to patch `\includegraphics`, I suggest 1) to not use a new definition of `_` by 1a) just using `\blanks` or 1b) a textual replacement by your editor that automatically replaces `____` with `\blanks` or 2) to let `_` only use the re-definition in places you specify with `\makeunderscoreweird`/`\makeunderscorenormal`.

Comment: I'm not sure about `\everymath`: it won't do any good if some math mode material has already been tokenized. Probably making `_` math active and defining the meaning of the active `_` to behave differently in math and non math mode would be better.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not very keen towards modifying the category codes. Here's an approach without it, that only changes the meaning of `\_`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \new@ifnextchar
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\blanks}[1][4em]{\rule{#1}{.4pt}}
\newcommand*{\blank}[1]{\blanks[\widthof{#1}]}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\_}{\blanks[.5em]\@doblanks}
\def\@doblanks{%
  \new@ifnextchar_{\blanks[.5em]\expandafter\@doblanks\@gobble}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item We are \____ sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
\item We are \______________ his skills qualify him for the job.
\item We are \blanks[7em] his skills qualify him for the job.
\item We are \blank{not} sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The second item has 14 underscores, corresponding to the 7em in the third item.

If you *really* want to avoid the initial backslash, then make `_` active:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand*{\blanks}[1][4em]{\rule{#1}{.4pt}}
\newcommand*{\blank}[1]{\blanks[\widthof{#1}]}

\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~}{\ifmmode\expandafter\sb\else\blanks[.5em]\fi}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \mathcode`\_="8000
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item We are ____ sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
\item We are ______________ his skills qualify him for the job.
\item We are \blanks[7em] his skills qualify him for the job.
\item We are \blank{not} sure that his skills qualify him for the job.
\end{itemize}

Some math $x_{1}$ and a URL \url{http://www.tex_stackexchange.com}

\end{document}
```